# jQuery date time event scheduler

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins, time, scheduler

I am unable to find a jQuery plugin that can help setup multiple event day scheduler along with validations on time. For instance, a typical schedule will look like this:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Topic</th>
    <th>From</th>
    <th>To</th>
    <th>Speaker</th>
    <th>Total Hours</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1. </td>
    <td><input type="text" size="10"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="10"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="7"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2. </td>
    <td><input type="text" size="10"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="10"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="7"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3. </td>
    <td><input type="text" size="10"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="10"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="7"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5"></td>
  </tr>
</table>  
<br/>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Topic</th>
    <th>From</th>
    <th>To</th>
    <th>Speaker</th>
    <th>Total Hours</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>29-05-2016</td>
    <td>Sample Topic 1</td>
    <td>01:00 PM</td>
    <td>03:30 PM</td>
    <td>Guest Speaker 1</td>
    <td>2:5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>29-05-2016</td>
    <td>Sample Topic 2</td>
    <td>04:00 PM</td>
    <td>04:30 PM</td>
    <td>Guest Speaker 2</td>
    <td>0.5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>29-05-2016</td>
    <td>Sample Topic 3</td>
    <td>05:00 PM</td>
    <td>07:00 PM</td>
    <td>Guest Speaker 3</td>
    <td>2.0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"></td>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>5.0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So basically, I need to validate:
1. To (Time) should not be less than From (Time)
2. From (Time) should not be less than To (Time) of preceding row.

I am using bootstrap.

Is there any plugin that I can use for this purpose?

Comment: Can't you just convert both _from time_ and _to time_ to a date object and compare the timestamps?